# HTML Email design(er?) to use with Membership Emails

Tags: html, wordpress, html-email

I am using ARmember to manage my membership on Wordpress. Within ARmember, they have the option to customise the emails sent to members (such as Email validation, Confirmation of account creation etc...). What they give me to use is the WYSIWYG editor along with some meta tags to add in (i.e {ARM_USERNAME}, {ARM_VERIFICATION_LINK} etc...)

I have no idea how to efficiently design responsive emails in HTML and I have tried using things like topol.io, beefree.io etc...) to which the designing part is fine, but when I copy their HTML to the email customizer of ARmember, the images are not linked (understandably) and it's not exactly responsive.

When I download those designs, they include an "Image" folder along with the HTML File. I have no idea where to copy that folder to. The root folder of WP install? Inside WP-Contents? No idea :(

If any of you have any suggestions, links to email builders that could solve this option, software perhaps? It's not like my designs are incredibly complicated. In fact, far from it. The only image I need linked is my Logo. The rest are just "functional" information such as links to verify the account and a few account notifications

I'm really sorry if this has been asked & answered before and I would appreciate any one's time, however little.

Cheers

Comment: use image hosting service like imgur and add image link from there

Comment: Will that show up on all email clients? What's the difference between hosting it on imgur vs my WP site?

Comment: if the link is correct, yes. not much a difference, but emails will show images even your site have some problems, imgur being popular service, have better reliability. other than that, each email client will treat images as external elements and probably ask for confirmation to display'em

Comment: You can use your own web site for email graphics. It might be a good idea to create a folder for them to help keep track of what is part of a specific email design.

Comment: I am going with @gwally, use your own site (or WP if its yours). Using imgur is not advised as its a free service and might end up showing images saying hotlinking is not allowed(maybe).

Comment: Okay cool - thanks so much guys. I'll give that a shot :)